# Add javascript event to jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid plugin and I want to add onKeyPress event to each field of edit form.

This code works for IE8, but fails in FF and IE7

```
 {name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 200, editable: true, 
     sortable: false, search: true, editoptions: { readonly: false, size: 32, 
     'onKeyPress': 'if($("#cbLanguage").attr("checked"))togeo();' }, 
     editrules: { required: true }}
```

How to modify this to make it work in IE7 and FF? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error? can you put in a console.log inside the function to see if it gets called. Have you got a demo url?

Comment: I don't get any error. And sadly no url. I'm testing it on local machine.

Comment: well try the console.log or a debugger statement inside the KeyUp function to see if it event gets called. Can you use firebug to see if the event gets added to the input box also

Comment: you could also use  a $('input.editClass').live('keyup' func). If you then add a class to the input when it is in edit mode the keyup event will bubble to the live handler and run your function

Comment: I tested it. and onkeypress event is never fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!
In order to assign event to field I need to add following to editoptions:

```
dataEvents:[{type:'keypress', fn: function(e) {
if($("#cbLanguage").attr("checked"))togeo(); }}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to karim79 for spotting the event issue.

In addition You will be better of using a function rather than an implied string as a function. Easy to read/maintain.

```
name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 200, editable: true, 
     sortable: false, search: true, editoptions: { readonly: false, size: 32, 
     'onKeyUp': keyUpFn }, 
     editrules: { required: true }}



function keyUpFn (){

 $("#cbLanguage").is(':checked') ){
   togeo();
 }

}
```